# Composer doesn't update my packages on LARAVEL, invalid JSON

Tags: laravel, composer-php

after running `composer update` I got this response:

> [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
>
> "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" does not contain
>   valid JSON
>
> Parse error on line 1:
>
> #!/usr/bin/env php<
>
> ^
>
> Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{',
>   '['

Already verified on jsonlint.com and it's OK, this is my code:

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
       "php": ">=5.5.9",
       "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use only your `composer.json` and run `composer install` with it, all works fine (except `/database`, because it doesn't exists by default). Could you reproduce?

Comment: Isn't that pointing to an error in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar itself?

Comment: To solve the issue I would try to delete the vendor folder and run composer self-update and composer install to see if the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution: CHANGE MY IDE DEFAULT CODING, TO ASCII FOR UTF-8. I dont
>   know why a good IDE do this ascii defa